# Meta box not appearing in my custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, metabox

I followed [this tutorial](http://wptheming.com/2010/08/custom-metabox-for-post-type/) on how to create a metabox on a custom post type I made and, at the time, it worked perfectly. the fist time worked like a charm. This time though, In a very similar environment, it just doesn't. The funny thing is, I can see the option to show or hide the metabox in the admin page. Also, if I mess up the `add_meta_box` bit, it adds a PHP error table inside the metabox otherwise missing.

Here's my current code in my functions.php:

```
// Custom post type arcticles
function create_arcticles()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'arcticles'); // Register Taxonomies for Category
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'arcticles');
    register_post_type('arcticles', // Register Custom Post Type
        array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('arcticles', 'arcticles'), // Rename these to suit
            'singular_name' => __('arcticle', 'arcticles'),
            'add_new' => __('Adicionar novo', 'arcticles'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Adicionar novo arcticle', 'arcticles'),
            'edit' => __('Editar', 'arcticles'),
            'edit_item' => __('Editar arcticle', 'arcticles'),
            'new_item' => __('Novo arcticle', 'arcticles'),
            'view' => __('Ver arcticle', 'arcticles'),
            'view_item' => __('Ver arcticle', 'arcticles'),
            'search_items' => __('Procurar por arcticles', 'arcticles'),
            'not_found' => __('Nenhum arcticle encontrado', 'arcticles'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nenhum arcticle encontrado no lixo', 'arcticles')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'excerpt'
        ),
        'can_export' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array(
            'post_tag',
            'category'
        ), // Add categories and tags
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_link_metaboxes'
    ));
}

// Add the meta box
function add_link_metaboxes () {
    add_meta_box( 'linkToArcticle', 'Link to arcticle', 'linkToArcticle', 'arcticles', 'default', 'normal' );
}

// Add Metabox content
function linkToArcticle() {
    global $post;
    // Noncename seems to be obligatory
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="eventmeta_noncename" id="eventmeta_noncename" value="' .
    wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';
    // Pegar o link se ele já foi gerado
    $link = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_link', true);
    // Echo the link's field
    echo '<input type="text" name="_link" value="' . $link  . '" class="widefat" />';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two parameters in `add_meta_box()` are switched. Look at the code in the tutorial next to yours:

```
// tutorial code
add_meta_box('wpt_events_location', 'Event Location', 'wpt_events_location', 'events', 'side', 'default');

// your code
add_meta_box( 'linkToArcticle', 'Link to arcticle', 'linkToArcticle', 'arcticles', 'default', 'normal' );
```

Change it to:

```
add_meta_box( 'linkToArcticle', 'Link to arcticle', 'linkToArcticle', 'arcticles', 'normal', 'default' );
```

And it will work